# Is there a shorter key combination than :cn to go to the next item in the quickfix list?

Tags: vim, search, vimgrep

I'm reading through a large C++ code base in Vim.

Within a single file, I can do

```
/foo
n
n
n
```

Now, if I want to search through more than one file, I have to do:

```
:vimgrep /foo/
:cn
:cn
:cn
```

Now, typing `:cn` is so much less convenient than `n`. Is there a way to search through vimgrep results with `n` (like searches with `/`) instead of `:cn`?

Comment: Hitting `.` usually repeats the last command.

Comment: @dirkgently The last edit command, I believe. Isn't there a different key for repeating the last ex command?

Comment: @Kazark Actually yes, the `@:` command repeats the last ex command.

Comment: @glts Right---thanks. Which, sadly, is barely shorter than `:cn`; but one character could add up over time if you got very used to hitting the `@` key.

Comment: @Kazark Right. In some cases, however, I need to repeat the last ex command *again* (after `@:`) and then I can do `@@` which is marginally more efficient than typing `@:` again.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `Quickfix List`. It will automatically be filled with found matches (no matter if you use `:grep` or `:vimgrep`). It can be navigated with the usual keys (so the key for "next" is `j` instead of `n`).

To open it use `:copen`.

Comment: Copen helps a lot when you have a lot of entries.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I have in my .vimrc exactly for this purpose:

```
nmap <F7> :cp^M
nmap <F8> :cn^M
```

Comment: +1 for the mapping...I use `noremap    <F4>   :<C-U>cnext <CR>` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option: the [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin binds `]q` to `:cnext` and `[q` to `:cNext` among many other useful keymappings.